# Valve for outdoor spigot cannot identify

Tags: outdoor, spigot

I cannot identify this Valve for an outdoor spigot I have the house was built in 1956 brick in and out so replacing entire spigot a real chore looking for valve replacement 
Any help would be appreciated

[image]

Comment: Try taking it to a plumbing supply store.

Comment: if you can't find a match it may be possible to replace the enitre valve upper retaining  the valve seat.and everything below.

Comment: I agree with jack, most all valve stems look the same or close, take it to a plumbing store and they will have what you need either a new stem or a complete valve.